# Hosts file Redirect website to about:blank

Tags: windows, redirect, hosts

I was just curious, how do I redirect a webaddress to a blank page using the windows Hosts file? All I know now is this `127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net`. So how do I redirect the address to a Blank page?

thanks

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: Well, I forgot to mention it's for a visual basic ad blocker app..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The HOSTS file assists in name resolution—converting a hostname to an IP address.
`about:blank` is a special URI that has nothing to do with name resolution.

You could run a webserver that sends 301 redirects to `about:blank` (or just sends blank pages), then add that server's IP address to the HOSTS file.

Comment: Yes how do I do that, all I want is a blank page! Even if it's a blank website.

Comment: like what ip should I put as a prefix in '127.0.0.1 googleads.g.doubleclick.net'

Comment: @Seif: The IP address of a server that sends a blank page on port 80.

Comment: @Slaks: well do you know any?

Comment: well, ive heard of a virus called TDss rootkit that edits the hosts file and redirects google to an about blank page...

Comment: i found the website : blank.org
how do i get its ip address?

Comment: You can ping it.  However, it's on shared hosting, so it won't work.  (you need a server that will ignore `Host:` headers)